# Xcode 6 Press Button to show multiple images

Tags: button, uiimage, xcode6

I want to add a UIImage and 2 buttons and every time you click the forward button it goes to the next image and when you hit the back button, it goes to the previous image. I don't know how to setup the code for this, would love some help! There will be 6 total pictures to cycle from

Answer (score 0):

> Step 1 :

Create scroll view, a view inside scroll view to act as container of images. Put all six images inside that view.two buttons for next and previous.

> Step 2:

Setup the width and height of scroll bar.
  As example : scroll view : height:200 width:200
               view : height:200, width: 1200 (as it holds six images)
               image width:200 each.

**Note** Don;t forget to set offset of each image. image one offset will b 0.image to will be 200 iamge 3 will be 400 and so on according to your image size.

> Step 3:

Set the delegate methods of scroll view.

> Step 4 :

make outlets for view,scroll view, buttons, and method for buttons.

> Step 5:

in did load section write this:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrContentSizeView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height);
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

> Step 6:

next button method:

```
 [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(200, 0) animated:YES];
```

where 200 is your starting of second image.
Similarly make previous button function.
It is up to you how you can change offset value dynamically.

Comment: i made a simple code and I have a UIImage, 2 buttons. In the code, the last button action is for the "Previous" button and that works great, but my next button doesn't. When I click on it, it stops and this pops up: "fatal error: Array index out of range." Also, how do I make it so that when the page loads, the first image is already loaded?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    IBAction func bttn(sender: AnyObject) {
        index--
        
        if index==resimler.count {index=0}
        image.image=UIImage(named: resimler[index])
        
    }
    
    
    IBAction func ilerle(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        index--
        
        if index<0 {index=resimler.count-1}
        image.image=UIImage(named: resimler[index])
    }